# android x navigation is not going back to host fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, androidx

android x navigation is not going back to host fragment when triggered from specific destionations

i tried lot of things but anything didn'twork for me

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? Please add more details to your questions or provide some code snippets.

Comment: there are a lot of answers with a lot of scenarios it depends on your code, as Mr. @Daniel said please provide some of your code with the fragment and activity scenario